# Alter sleep settings

Tags: settings, suspend

My Dell Inspiron laptop goes to sleep too soon for me - how do I alter that in Elementary Hera? I am unable to find any clues in this library.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Applications/System Tools/System Settings/Power. Suspend settings are in there - authenticate to change these as required.